# Javascript regex match doesn't contain keyword

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to match a string that not start with keyword "side" (case sensitive)...

I have tried like this: `/^(?!side).*$/i` 
but don't work for me because I would like to accept for example: "side1", "side 1"

I hope I was clear

**Edited:**

- Expression cannot contain only the word "side" with any given case.
- If the expression has the word **side** it must be accompanied by *something else* meaning more characters.

Bye

Comment: In what sense does `"side 1"` not start with the keyword "side"?

Comment: yes... but for me is only wrog "side", "Side", "SIDE", "sIdE". All the other it's ok

Comment: @FrancescoG. what you are saying is that "Side" is incorrect but "Side *something else*" is correct

Comment: OK, one more time: how does `"side 1"` **not** start with "side"?  (Note that it **does** start with "side".)

Comment: Yes @Dalorozo... "Sidesomething else" is correct too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I would to take a leap of faith here...

```
(?!^side$)\b.+\b
```

**[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nX8iA1/3)**

Comment: Now this regex is same as my answer :)

Comment: yesss... thank so much to everybody! For me regex is arabic

Answer (score 1):

You can use this negative regex with word boundary:

```
/^(?!side$)/i
```

Comment: this does not seem to be the answer of unclear question

Comment: It's ok for "side1", but no for "side 1"

Comment: still it is not matching anything just avoid to match side

Comment: What do you mean by not matching anything? [Check this regex](https://regex101.com/r/eT8cE7/1) There are 2 matches

Comment: what is the matching pattern of your expression above? There is only a Negative Lookahead but nothing else

Comment: Negative lookahead is the one failing the match. Run it with `re.test` and see what returns false/true

Comment: If you are just looking for highlighting part on regex101 then use `/^(?!side$).+/i`

Comment: @FrancescoG.: May I know why you decided to remove acceptance mark from this answer after so many months?